# flash video player issue

Tags: xml, flash

We are using a flash video player. In that we are passing an xml URL as Flashvars which contains the path of the flv video to be played in that player. This works fine when we are uploading to the test server. But we have a development sever which is accessed by an ip address. Whenever any ip address xml URL is sent to the flash, it is not playing the video.

Any thoughts on this?

Seems to be very strange issue

When we use domain_name/video_player it is working fine and xml file is loading

But when we use ip_address_of_domain/video_player, XML is not loading Seems to be really strange

Comment: Seems to be very strange issue

When we use domain_name/video_player it is working fine and xml file is loading

But when we use ip_address_of_domain/video_player, XML is not loading Seems to be really strange

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a cross-domain issue. Are you getting any errors? Do you have a cross-domain.xml set up? If php is a possibility on your server, you could also use a proxy to get around the cross-domain issues (if that is the case).

Comment: there is no cross domain XMLs. We are calling a URL with domain name. Video player is working there.

We are calling the same URL with that domain's IP address. Then it is not loading the XML file into flash player. This is the issue